# Question concerning relationships between different $p$-modular systems and Brauer character values

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, fields

Let $(K,\mathcal{O},k)$ be a large enough $p$-modular system, where $\mathcal{O}$ is a complete discrete valuation ring of characteristic zero with unique maximal ideal $J(\mathcal{O})$, algebraically closed residue field $k=\mathcal{O}/J(\mathcal{O})$ of characteristic $p$, and field of fractions $K=\text{Frac}(\mathcal{O})$, which we assume to be large enough for $G$ and its subgroups in the sense that $K$ contains a root of unity of order $\text{exp}(G)$.

I‘d like to consider two different instances of the above situation:

1)

Let $R$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $\mathbb{C}$. Choose a maximal ideal $m$ of $R$ containing $pR$. The quotient $F = R/m$ is a field of characteristic $p$. Let $^{*}: R\rightarrow F$ denote the natural projection. Furthermore, let $S = R_m$ be the localization of $R$ at $m$.
We can extend ${}^{*}$ to $S$ by setting ${(\frac{r}{s})}^{*}= r^* (s^* )^{-1}$ for every $\frac{r}{s}\in S$ . Now, set $U = \{\xi \in \mathbb{C}\ |\ \exists\ m \in \mathbb{N}\ \text{such that}\ \xi^m = 1\ \text{and}\ p\nmid m\}$, the
multiplicative group of $p'$-roots of unity.

Lemma: The restriction of ${}^{*}$ to $U$ defines an isomorphism $U \rightarrow F^{\times}$ of multiplicative groups. Moreover, $F$ is the algebraic closure of its prime field $Z^{*} \cong F_p$.

Consequently, the Brauer character values are complex numbers.

2)

Suppose someone takes an algebraically closed field $k'$ of characteristic $p$ such that the degree of a transcendence basis of $k'$ is much larger than that of $F$ in the first instance. Then, $\mathcal{O}'$ is a free $W(k')$-module of rank $e$, where $W(k')$ denotes the ring of Witt vectors and $e$ is the absolute ramification index of $\mathcal{O}'$. Set $K':=Frac(\mathcal{O}')$, the field of fractions of $\mathcal{O}'$.

**Question(s):**

1. How can one relate the values of the $K'$-valued Brauer characters of instance 2 to the complex numbers of the $\mathbb{C}$-valued Brauer characters of instance 1?
2. Can complex numbers come into the picture in case 2 such that we can compare 1 and 2 directly?
3. Can one just use the fact that every algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$ contains an algebraic closure of its prime field and use that as a bridge in order to translate between complex numbers and elements in $K'$?

Am I missing any details / caveats?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Big point. Brauer characters are only defined over $\mathbb C$, they do not come from the underlying field. You take the eigenvalues of a matrix representing the element, work them out as roots of unity, then map those roots of unity over to $\mathbb C$ via a fixed bijection before any addition. Otherwise the character value of a $p$-dimensional representation at the identity would be $0$. The roots of unity always lie in a finite field in characteristic $p$, so you can make $K$ as big as you want with no issue.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you very much for your comment. Things make more sense now.   :-)